# ~したいと思います Does it mean exactly as translated? I think I want to

Tags: grammar

I frequently hear this pattern when watching Japanese TV.
From a japanese native's perspective is this the only meaning to it:
"I think I want to ~"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think we say [したいと思います](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%22) to mean "would like to do (now)", and [したいと思っています](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%22) to mean "would like to/hope to do (in the future)". I think したいと思います/と思っています sounds politer (and humbler?) than したいです.

Comment: I see thank you for clearing that up with your explanation about its usage.

Comment: @JonathanC: Welcome to JLU. If you feel this answer is correct, please mark it with the check mark just underneath the up and down arrows to the left of the text.